Pandas saving to file - only last DataFrame is saved
I'm using a function to drop a record from DataFrame in file and when I try to execute a function a few times it drops only last record. Why does it work like that?
Here's some code.
def delete_title(title):
    i = file[file.TITLE == title].index[0]
    df = file.drop(file.index[i])
    df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False)

I expect it to drop all the records when I'm executing a function a few times f.e. I used a function 3 times and I want it to delete 3 records.
Thanks for answers ;)

You are specifying one constant filename for all your dfs. Which causes them to overwrite to the same file.

So how can I fix this?

Choose a dynamic filename. Something like f"filename-{title}"

As @Parman M. Alizadeh suggested, you use the same filename for all saving actions which overrides the previous once.
The solution is to use a different name for each dataframe you would like to save.
For instance:
def delete_title(title):
    i = file[file.TITLE == title].index[0]
    df = file.drop(file.index[i])
    df.to_csv(f"filename_{title}.csv", index=False)

Or you can use the current timestamp instead:
import datetime
def delete_title(title):
    cur_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    i = file[file.TITLE == title].index[0]
    df = file.drop(file.index[i])
    df.to_csv(f"filename_{cur_timestamp}.csv", index=False)

Feel free to comment if you have any questions.
Goodluck!
